# Showing that $\sum_{r=1}^{N} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi irs}{N}\right)=0$ when $0<s<N$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I am trying to show that

$$\sum_{r=1}^{N} \exp\left(\frac{2\pi irs}{N}\right)=0$$ when $0<s<N$. This result is stated in a [paper](https://www.dna.caltech.edu/courses/cs191/paperscs191/turing.pdf) by A. Turing (see page $39$). I can see how it is a geometric progression (as suggested by Turing), but do not understand how the result follows.

Comment: In the complex plane, these are the points of a regular N-gon on the unit circle. Their average is clearly the origin, so their sum is 0. Also, $\sum_{r=0}^{N-1} a^r = (1-a^N)/(1-a)$ gives it.

Comment: Do note that $s$ is required to be an integer.  The sum makes sense regardless, but it doesn't have the required value for any real $s$.  In this context, there's a slight correction to the comment of @JoshuaP.Swanson that the points are the vertices of a regular $\dfrac{N}{\gcd(s,N)}$-gon on the unit circle, each counted $\gcd(s,N)$ times, but the conclusion doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align*}
\sum_{r=1}^{N}\exp(\frac{2i\pi rs}{N}) &= \sum_{r=1}^{N}{\exp(\frac{2i\pi s}N)}^{r}\\
&=\underbrace{\exp(\frac{2i\pi s}N)}_{= \alpha}\sum_{r=0}^{N-1}{\exp(\frac{2i\pi s}N)}^r\\
&= \alpha \frac{1-\alpha^N}{1-\alpha} \text{ because } \alpha \neq 1 \text{ as } 0 < s < N
\end{align*}$

Now, we see that $\alpha^N = {\exp(\frac{2i\pi s}N)}^N = \exp(2i\pi s) = 1$ because $s$ is an integer, so the sum is indeed equal to $0$.

Of course, other interpretations given in the comments, like geometric considerations of how this amounts to compute some kind of barycenter are completely valid, but usually require a bit more "hand-waving" and might be hard to understand if you're not too familiar with how complex numbers/the complex plane work. The "bruteforce" computation of the geometric sum, on the other hand, requires little visualisation or intuition, and is (in my opinion) easier to generalise to similar problems.